# Undefined variable: $_post xampp server

Tags: php, post, xampp

I tried to run this code ,but the output I got was:

Notice: Undefined variable: _post in E:\xampp\htdocs\testphp.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined variable: _post in E:\xampp\htdocs\testphp.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined variable: _post in E:\xampp\htdocs\testphp.php on line 6

First Name:- Last Name:- Other Details :

This is the code of my form:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="testphp.php">
<label for="firstname">First Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /> </br></br>

<label for="lastname">Last Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /> </br></br>

<label for="other"> Other Details: </label>
<textarea name="other" ></textarea></br></br>

<input type="submit" value="Ok -- submit" name=submit  />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the code in testphp.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
$last_name= $_POST['lastname'];
$otherdetail= $_POST['other'];

echo 'First Name:- '. $first_name;
echo 'Last Name:- '. $last_name;
echo 'Other Details :- '. $otherdetail;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me!

Comment: Any idea of why there's a lowercase `_post` in the error messages?

Comment: + are you sure you used the form to go to the script?

Comment: Put some quotes in `name=submit`

Comment: Try using get method,just to know if its a system error of some sort.I had an experience where because of a virus the rename(); function in php never worked,but after reinstalling windows it worked without any modifications

Comment: Hey...I just copy pasted this exact code in my system and it worked fine.

Comment: Code's fine. Nothing wrong with this. Are you sure you're running these exact files and you may have used `$_post` at first instead of `$_POST` and didn't use the updated version?

Comment: The only way that this could produce that error, least from what I tested is, if both bodies of code are inside the same file, then yes, it will produce those error messages. Or, you're accessing the `testphp.php` file directly instead of the form, if it's in a file of its own. Use `isset()`

Answer (score 1):

I just copy pasted this exact code in my system and it worked fine.

from the error message it seems like you called the testphp.php from a different html file.Make sure you saved the changes before running it in browser...both files.

There is nothing wrong with the code.I just copy pasted without any modification and it worked well.

Sometimes the problem may be with your PHP configuration file.Please verify your PHP configuration file for superglobal variables is enabled or not.The best way to setup a development server is by individullay installing Apache,PHP and MySQL instead of using Packages of all.This gives you a through knowledge of your configurations and you can quickely troubleshoot errors of this sort.

I had an experience where because of a virus the rename(); function in php never worked,but after reinstalling windows it worked without any modifications.So please verify if you have any problem with OS.Try executing your code in other system with the same setup(I insists on this solution because your code worked fine on my system!!)